# jQuery $.each break issue

Tags: jquery, loops, each

I have a function to check elements of class `.sitem` and if any of them has blank value , it should return , else he code should go on.

```
if($(".sitem").each(function(ss, element) {

if($(this).val()=="")
{
alertify.error("item name can't be left blank");
return true;
}
return false;
}))
{
return;
}

//go on with your code
```

the function works when the value is blank it alertify me , and returns false , the problem when the item has value , it doesnt go on with code , any hints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `.each()` returns a jQuery object which will always be truthy(irrespective of the values returned from the each handler.... if you return false it just terminates the further iteration of the element set)

One solution is to use a valid state variable like

```
var valid = true;

$(".sitem").each(function (ss, element) {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        alertify.error("item name can't be left blank");
        valid = false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
})

if (!valid) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return true // continue loop

return false // breaks loop
```

So,

```
var is_valid = true;

$(".sitem").each(function(ss, element) {
    if($(this).val()=="") {
        alertify.error("item name can't be left blank");
        is_valid = false;
        return false;
    }
});

if(!is_valid) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: i know this already !! still the code doesnt go on as it should !

Comment: it does same as my code pilot the code doesnt go on s it should !